# Tornado PeriodicCallback will create a new context

Tags: python, tornado

I encounter some strange behavior of [PeriodicCallback in Python Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html).

```
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}
        PeriodicCallback(self._check_status, 3000).start()
    ...
    def foo(self):
        self.dict["efg"] = 20 
        print (id(self.dict)) # 1st print

    def _check_status(self):
        self.dict["abc"] = 10
        print ( id(self.dict)) # 2nd print
```

The 1st and 2nd print value is different, meaning self.dict are different object, which causes serious problem. This is unexpected behavior. What is wrong?

I want self.dict referring to the same object in foo and in _check_status. What should I do?

Comment: What is `it`? Do you mean `id`?

Comment: @Sraw yes, updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering how do you use this `MyClass` in practice? Could you provide something more? As sometimes you will implicitly create multiple instances.

Comment: Code given by you is not enough for meaningful answer as problem's cause is outside of this scope.